# HTTP/1.1, webSocket and HTTP/2.0 analysis in terms of Socket

Tags: sockets, http, websocket

I need to know how HTTP/1.1, webSocket and HTTP/2.0 works in terms of Socket (I am not interested in a list of different features between these three technologies).

So, when I start an HTTP/1.1 request I know that after server response, my connection will be closed.
But, let me say, When I start an HTTP/1.1. request, at transport layer level, a socket will be inizialized to send my HTTP request (header and data) to the webserver.

So I have three questions:

1. If HTTP/1.1 implements a socket (open from my pc and webserver) to send its request, why it can not use that socket to implement request-response cycle more and more times ?
2. Is The principal different between HTTP/1.1 and webSocket the fact that HTTP/1.1 close the socket after the first request-response cycle and webSocket don't close the socket after first cycle ?
3. How HTTP/2.0 manages socket between client and server ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you start an HTTP/1.1 request you know that the connection will be *kept alive* after the response, unless you request otherwise. Your question is based on a false premise.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

1. Actually, HTTP/1.1 allows the connection to be used for more than a single request by using the "keep-alive" feature.

   This means that multiple HTTP/1.1 requests might be sent over a single TCP/IP connections.

   However, since HTTP/1.1 doesn't allow for multiplexing, the requests (and responses) are serialized, which might cause a longer request/response to delay short request/response due to the strict queue.

   FYI: closing the connection is an HTTP/1 approach, where the end of a response would be marked by the socket closing. On HTTP/1.1, the end of the response is usually known by the "Content-Length" header (or the chunked encoding marker).
2. No, the difference is much bigger. The WebSocket protocol isn't a request-response protocol, it's a message based protocol, which is a totally different beast.

   In effect, you can think about WebSockets as more similar to TCP/IP than to HTTP, except that TCP/IP is a streaming protocol and WebSockets is a message based protocol...

   The WebSockets protocol promises that messages don't arrive fragmented while TCP/IP `read` calls might return a fragment of a message (or more than a single message).
3. HTTP/2.0 uses a single connection, but it has a binary message wrapping layer that allows the server and the client to multi-plex (manage more than a single information stream using a single connection).

   This means that the request-response queue is parallel (instead of the HTTP/1.1 serial queue). For example, a response to request #2 might arrive before a response to request #1.

   This solves the HTTP/1.1 issue of "pipelining" and message ordering, where a long request/response cycle might cause all the other requests to "wait".

   There are other properties and differences, but in some ways this is probably the main one (in addition to other performance factors such as header compression, binary data formats, etc').